# wrangling data in jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Error whilst trying to gather twitter data.

I have been given some info for twitter API but it seems i have problems even copying and pasting. When looping through the data it keeps failing, could someone point me in the direction of what is going wrong please?

https://gist.github.com/PWynter/fddecee280b6a398e2a03e129b4dbb46

i must be blind as i really can't see the error

https://gist.github.com/PWynter/fddecee280b6a398e2a03e129b4dbb46

Expected the return of print success

Comment: Instead of printing 'Fail' could you print the error please? `print(e)`

Comment: print the error.